# Create Swing GUI Elements for each item in a Collection - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, linked-list

If I have a collection of objects:

```
public class Party {
    LinkedList<Guy> partyList = new LinkedList<Guy>();

    public void addGuy(Guy c) {
        partyList.add(c);
    }
}
```

And a tabbedPane:

```
public class CharWindow
{
private JFrame  frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                CharWindow window = new CharWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public CharWindow()
{
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 727, 549);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JTabbedPane PartyScreen = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Party Screen", null, PartyScreen, null);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane_2 = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
    tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, tabbedPane_2, null);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane_3 = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
    tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, tabbedPane_3, null);
}
}
```

How would I add content to the tabbedPane "Party Screen" such that it displays a JLabel "Name" and a vertical JSeparator for each item in my LinkedList?

Comment: What is `PartyScreen`? Where is it defined? Also, [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is a wrapper class for the primitive `char` -- is this what you intended?

Comment: Just fixed that name clash, and `PartyScreen` is a tabbedPane

Comment: D'oh. I need to learn to read more carefully. Sorry.

Comment: I think, if anything, I need to learn how to post only appropriate code, but I'm new to all this GUI lark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, JTabbedPane is the widget that creates a new tab for each element panel. It is *not* the child of a tabbed interface. (Eg. JTabbedPane should hold a JPanel called partyScreen.)

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPanel = new JTabbedPane(); // holds all tabs

// this is how you add a tab:
JPanel somePanel = new JPanel();
tabbedPanel.addtab("Some Tab", somePanel);

// this is how you'd add your party screen
JPanel partyScreen = new JPanel();
tabbedPanel.addTab("Party Screen", partyScreen);
```

Remember, Java naming convention has a variable start with a lower case letter -- so partyScreen is preferred to PartyScreen.

Then iterate through each `Guy` object in `Party` and add the appropriate components. I have no idea why you're using a `LinkedList` instead of a `List`, but I'll assume you have a good reason not included in the code above.

```
// myParty is an instance of Party; I assume you have some sort of accessor to 
// the partyList
LinkedList<Guy> partyList = myParty.getPartyList();
ListIterator<Guy> it = partyList.listIterator();
while( it.hasNext() ) {
    Guy g = it.next();
    partyScreen.add(new JLabel( g.getName() ));
    partyScreen.add(new JSeparator() );
}
```

Depending on how you want it to be arranged in the `partyScreen` panel, you'll probably want to look into a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).